# Install Debian from ISO of install CD without burning a CD or using a USB drive

Tags: debian, installation, grub, iso-image, grub2

I want to install Debian to an empty partition of my computer. The computer is already running Debian on a different partition and has GRUB2 installed. I downloaded the CD image from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/weekly-builds/amd64/iso-cd/debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso). I then copied it to `/data` and added a menuentry to `grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry "Debian install image" {
    set isofile="/data/debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso"
    loopback loop (hd0,2)$isofile
    echo "Starting $isofile..."
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz findiso=$isofile priority=low vga=788 ---
    initrd (loop)/install.amd/initrd.gz
}
```

This boots up the installer and everything seems fine. Unfortunately, the CDROM cannot be detected. I have searched and found several threads that suggest I need to mount the contents of the CD to `/cdrom`, but if I switch to a new console with `ATL + F2` and try to mount anything it either says `invalid argument` or something similar. I double-checked `/dev` and the hard disk special files are all there (`sda`, `sda1`, ...).  I tried like 10 different guides and nothing works.

1. What do I need to do to continue installation?
2. Which other options do I have to install without physical CDROM drive or USB thumb drive?

I'm fairly sure there is a working guide somewhere and that I simply cannot find it. Please point me to one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer to the 2nd point:
If you have a Debian and want to install Debian somewhere else, just install package debootstrap.
From its manpage:

```
Debootstrap can be used to install Debian in a system without using an
installation disk but can also be used to run a different Debian flavor
in  a  chroot  environment.
```

just mount your installation partition to `/mnt` and try: `debootstrap stretch /mnt` .

You might end having to do some GRUB tweaking at the end for the dual boot.

For your first point: the installation CD boots (using el torito or grub depending on media) with minimally populated ramdisk image, that's way smaller than the whole CD image. It lacks any but the most vital kernel modules. It does lack ext4 (or btrfs...), and it also lacks loop (used to mount file images). So you have a chicken and egg problem: to mount the CD (image) containing those missing kernel modules you need those missing kernel modules.

Either put the CD image directly in a partition (without filesystem) and tweak GRUB to boot from it. The installation should hopefully detect the CD (image).

Or put it on a vfat filesystem, because vfat happens to be present in the initial booted image (but not ext4, btrfs ...). Then retrieve from the CD image itself (before installing) or from ftp.debian.org/debian the missing loop-modules .udeb file, and put it too on the vfat filesystem. Path of the file should be something like:

```
/pool/main/l/linux-signed/loop-modules-4.7.0-1-amd64-di_4.7.6-1_amd64.udeb
```

Of course the exact udeb name will change over time.

UPDATE: It was also mentionned that the [hd-media initrd.gz image](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/) contains directly all of the needed modules (including loop, ext4 ...). It's a compressed cpio image so could even be usable at boot with busybox which can handle both gunzip and cpio ( `cd / && gunzip < /path/to/initrd.gz | cpio -i` ) and can be faster than udpkg.

Then from the ALT+F2 console, you can mount your vfat partition (`mount -t vfat /dev/sdX /mnt`), use `udpkg -i` to "install" the installation .udeb and `modprobe loop`
Now either the installation should work (menu: detect and mount CDROM if it failed before ), or if it doesn't you can try to mount it with `mkdir -p /cdrom; mount -o ro,loop -t iso9660 /mnt/debian-testing-amd64-netinst.iso /cdrom` and hope for the best.

Comment: Yes the missing modules I could figure out. I wonder why they would not pack any filesystem driver except vfat? At least ext2 would be a good idea :-/ Anyways I will play around a bit and see if I get it working.

Comment: Another work around is noted here: borrow the fat initrd img from hd-install : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199339/grub-boot-debian-iso-file-from-ntfs-partition-and-install-it

Comment: Indeed there are many modules already present in this file so it's faster than tracking all .udeb. I'll add a pointer about hd-media (I won't put a full walk-through)